# No intellisense in Visual Studo 2017 for new C# files

Tags: visual-studio, intellisense, visual-studio-2017

When I add new `.cs` file to my project, file is added to **Miscellaneous Files** and then I don't get no intellisense and red squiggles.

[image]

Comment: Glad to hear that your issue is solved and you can mark your reply as answer when you have free time, it will help other community members who meet the same or similar issue to easier search this workaround :)

Comment: @Sara-MSFT Will do, but have to wait for 24h to accept it, 4 hour more :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Problem was with enabled lightweight solution loading, when I disabled it and restarted Visual Studio it all started to work again.

Comment: Hi, please mark your reply as answer when you have free time, it will help other community members who meet the same issue to easier search this useful information :)

Comment: Totally forgot:)